# Chromebook keeps turning wi-fi off, then back on

Tags: wireless-networking, chromebook

My Samsung chromebook has developed an odd wi-fi behaviour.  I have eliminated both signal problems and router as causes and I have stopped all running apps but the problem remains.

The wi-fi status indicator on the right hand end of the taskbar keeps alternating between *Wi-Fi Disabled* and *Wi-Fi Enabled*.  It changes state roughly every two seconds.

While enabled, the Chromebook doesn't manage to connect to the router before it disables again.

There is no consistent failure message which may cause the disabling.  Sometimes the chromebook reports "*Obtaining IP Address*" but often fails to get that far.

A chromebook has limited logging and diagnostic facilities so I've failed so far to get any sensible idea as to why this has happened.  I've tried clearing every cache I can find in both *crosh* and *chrome://net-internals*, without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Push ALT and T at the same time and use this command and see if you get any details    "network_logging wifi"